# How do you get last modified dates of all files within a folder and compare it to a certain date? php

Tags: php, datetime, last-modified, strpos, filemtime

Does anyone know a way to grab the last modified dates of all files within a folder and compare it to a certain date?

So far I have this.

```
<?php
    $lastmoddate = (date("Ymd", filemtime($file)));
    $todaysdate = date("Ymd", time());

    $result = array(); 
    $folder = ('uploaded_files/');     
    $handle = opendir($folder);

    foreach (glob("$folder/*") as $team){$sort[]= end(explode('/',$team));}

    while (false !==($file = readdir($handle)))
    {
        if ( $file != ".." && $file != "." )
        {
            $file = "uploaded_files/".$file ;
            if (!is_dir($file))
                $result[] = $file;
        } 
    }
    closedir($handle);


    foreach ($result as $file){
        if ($lastmoddate > $todaysdate){
            if (strpos($file, "+12:00") !==false){
                echo "$file".",".date ("h:i d/m/Y", filemtime($file))."\r\n"."<br/>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

This doesn't work as $lastmoddate = gives me the date 1969 12 31.

Comment: please learn to indent your code. it is hard as hell to read it when you trying to sort things out. -1 so far.

Comment: do your files **really** have a "+12:00" part in their **names**

Comment: Sorry, I've just started learning php.
Will try cleaning code up.

Yeah my files are called "+12:0004:31 06.11.2011-Banner.jpg"

what i wanted to do was note down the TIMEZONEs in file names

Answer (score 0):

PHP's [filemtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) (which internally basically just calls [`stat()`](http://php.net/stat) and returns only the m-time value) works on a single file at a time.

You've already got a `glob()` call in your script to get a list of filenames. Put the filemtime() call inside that loop to get each file's mtime, and do the comparisons in there.

Your code is not working as you've not assigned a value to `$file` at the point you do the initial  filemtime() call, so that returns a boolean `FALSE` for failure, which gets converted to an integer `0` for the `date()` formatting. You're in a timezone that's negative-GMT, so that converts to a date slightly BEFORE Jan 1/1970, which is time 0 in UTC.

What you need is:

```
foreach (glob("$folder/*") as $team) { 
    $lastmoddate = filemtime("$folder/$team");
    ... date stuff ...
    $sort[]= basename($team);
}
```

Comment: Would This be the right way to write it out for the "date stuff"  http://codepad.org/br26FKt3

Answer (score 0):

So far I can see 2 inconsistent things in your code.

1. you are getting lastmoddate only **once**, not for the existing files but for some undefined (yet) $file
2. you date copmparison makes no sense. Say, even if your file has been modified today, it's date never be **more than** today's date, so, all your comparisons will fail for sure. At least use `>=` or `==` to compare, not `>`

Comment: The files have been modified in a -10GMT and the website is based in a +10GMT. So $todaysdate means -10GMT.

from what you can see... what would the $file value be?